# any command that can format html or xml from shell?

Tags: text-processing, sed, html

There must be something on the lines of `sed`?

Normally in `sed` you type something like:

```
echo day | sed s/day/night/
```

the shell prints "night".

Is there something that can take a file (containing xml/html) or an xml/html string and return the formatted result for me?

Ps: want to be able to use this from my editor...

Comment: `sed` doesn't really have to do anything with formatting, id is a (primarily line-oriented) Stream EDitor.

Comment: Do you mean something like "pretty printed" or indented?

Comment: If you need this, you need to change editors. Try a 'real' one like emacs or vim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If its something related to pretty printing of file in xml aligned format, xmllint as suggested by @warl0ck is nice & here is what I tried & see:

```
$cat some.xml
<myRoot> <my-element><my-subelem myAttr="value"/></my-element></myRoot>


$ xmllint --format some.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myRoot>
  <my-element>
    <my-subelem myAttr="value"/>
  </my-element>
</myRoot>
```

Comment: Can it take a string as argument itself, as opposed to a file?

Comment: Well, I tried it by echo`ing & it worked in that case as well:

 xmllint --format  <(echo '<myRoot> <my-element><my-subelem myAttr="value"/></my-element></myRoot>')

Any specific use-case where your are seeing some failure?.

Comment: how to utilize that for the geany editor: http://www.geany.org/manual/#sending-text-through-custom-commands

Answer (score 2):

Try the `xmllint` program.

In VIM you could format the whole file in place, e.g `1,$!xmllint --format --recover -`